# Headphone option missing in mixer

Tags: sound

I just installed 4.13.0-36-generic on a spare drive.  MB is a Supermicro C2SEA, so RealTek ALC888.  Everything is working, but my headphones.  I have searched around on Google and found little information that was helpful.  Sound works on my regular speakers.  When I plug in the headphones into front headphone jack, I still hear sounds from speakers only.
Sound settings show only Line Out and Digital Output (S/PDIF). No Headphones listed.  I have tried the suggestion: alsactl restore but no change.  Any suggestions? Thanks in advance, it's been a long time since I worked with Linux.

Answer (score 1):

try PulseAudio, and select proper playback/output device/port.